# Used diskpart to convert format, infinite boot menu

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios

I tried installing Windows on a [Lenovo IdeaPad 3](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/ideapad-300-series/IdeaPad-3-15ARE05/p/88IPS301432) that I just bought (from a USB stick). It told me that I can't install Windows on GBT format, so I had to format the disk.

I followed [these](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-installation-issue-cant-install-windows/ec4114d6-a036-457d-bec8-139dc77c5898) instructions to the letter:

> 1. Boot from the installation device (USB or DVD).
> 2. Once you reach the "Install" page. Immediately press and hold SHIFT KEY + F10 KEY. This will open command prompt (The black box DOS
>    program).
> 3. Once the Command Prompt is open, proceed to type the following command line.

> Method 1:Short Method
>
> 1. Type diskpart and then hit enter. This will enable command prompt to enter disk partitioning mode.
> 2. Now type list disk and then hit enter. You will then see a list of disk drives.
> 3. Please make sure that you know the current size of your HDD. Select it by typing select disk 0 . Replace 0 with the right drive number.
> 4. Now type clean to unallocated it.
> 5. Now type create part pri and hit enter to create primary partition.
> 6. Next is to type select part 1 and then hit enter.
> 7. Now type format fs=ntfs quick and then hit enter. Take note this will reformat the whole hard drive. So make sure you have a backup of everything.
> 8. Now type select disk 0 again and then hit enter.
> 9. Now please type detail disk and then hit enter.
> 10. You will see a volume number, type select volume 1.
> 11. Now please type delete volume.
> 12. Now type convert mbr if you need gpt then type convert gpt and then
>     hit enter.
> 13. Now please go so step c up to step g then type exit.

Now I can't get past the boot menu:

[image]

What is the issue and what is there to do so I can get Windows on this machine?

Comment: That's a weird tutorial; steps e-k are achieving _literally nothing_ in it... Anyway. 1) How did you make the USB stick? Did you use the Media Creation Tool, or did you use Rufus or something else? 2) What happens if you select option 3 in the boot menu?

Comment: 1) I used the media creation tool for the usb. I think the usb itself is ok, as it booted up the first time to install windows. 

2) Any option I select the screen will go black for 1-2 seconds and then this menu will be presented again

Comment: Boot from the windows 10 install media, when you get to the page that lists the disks, choose advanced options, then highlight and delete any partitions, then hit the next button to install windows.

Comment: Ok, so with that diskpart I managed to delete the USB  also not only the partition, remaking the USB stick and following what Moab said fixed this issue :D